# Terraform Version Update

Tags: environment-variables, command-line-interface, terraform

all.
I'm trying to update my Terraform CLI to version 0.12.18. I'm currently on 0.12.9.
I downloaded the .exe from the site and unzipped it, but when I use the terraform version command, It's still telling me that I'm on version 0.12.9. I've placed the .exe in a folder in C, and updated the system environment variable to point to that directory. There are no other terraform directories or files anywhere on my pc that I can find, so I have no idea where my command line is looking to get the 0.12.9 version. I'm on Windows 10, 64-bit. Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks.

````
Terraform v0.12.9

Your version of Terraform is out of date! The latest version
is 0.12.18. You can update by downloading from www.terraform.io/downloads.html```

variable name: terraform
variable value: C:\Users\realm\Projects\terraform_0.12.18_windows_amd64\
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is on windows. Start a new Command Prompt and type

```
echo %PATH%
```

It should show you all the directories you have in your path environment variable.  Check those directories and make sure there isnt another copy of the terraform.exe file in there.

[echo %PATH% Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xg3qz.png)

Comment: When I put in that command, the first thing that popped up in the output was "c:\terraform"
But, that directory doesn't even exist, and it's not listed in the window for my environment variables. How can I fix that to make it look at the right directory, if not by editing the system environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tfswitch` as an alternative while developing the code. You can install tfswitch and while developing terraform code, you can have `.tfswitch` file with version in it and while running the code, just call tfswitch first and this will switch to particular version mentioned in the `.tfswitch` file.

Example: `ls -la /Users/admin/terraform-test`

```
drwxr-xr-x  23 admin  admin   736  5 Jul 12:12 .
drwxr-xr-x  23 admin  admin   736 15 Jun 14:38 ..
drwxr-xr-x   6 admin  admin   192  7 May 14:28 .terraform
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  admin  6932 16 Jun 09:02 .terraform.lock.hcl
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  admin     6 13 May 11:18 .tfswitchrc
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  admin   125 20 May 09:27 data.tf
```

```
cat /Users/admin/terraform-test/.tfswitchrc
0.15.3
```